# Read data from MongoDB using DataStage

Tags: mongodb, datastage

I'm using IBM DataStage 8.7 and need to read data from a MongoDB instance. I've searched for a connector but can't find anything available for this version.

I know this is an old version of DataStage and my company is planning an upgrade but that will take at least 6 months.

So in the meantime I'd be grateful if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked at tte KonwledgeCenter documentation?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.odbc.help.doc/topics/odbc_mongo.html

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher that document is for version 11.7. I'm using version 8.7 which is no longer supported.